# time to display in dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I can use jquery or dojo or simple HTML to show hours and minutes in separate dropdown list. Please suggest.
Below is the sample code:

```
<input id="time" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox" required="true"
data-dojo-props="constraints: { timePattern: 'HH:mm:ss', clickableIncrement: 'T00:05:00', visibleIncrement: 'T00:05:00', visibleRange: 'T01:00:00' }" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about dojo but i got this far if it helps:

```
Time:
<input id="timeHours" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox" required="true" data-dojo-props="constraints: { timePattern: 'HH', clickableIncrement: 'T01:05:00', visibleIncrement: 'T01:00:00', visibleRange: 'T24:00:00' }" />
:
<input id="timeMins" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox" required="true" data-dojo-props="constraints: { timePattern: 'mm', clickableIncrement: 'T00:05:00', visibleIncrement: 'T00:05:00', visibleRange: 'T00:60:00' }" />

require([
    "dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/registry", "dojo/ready", "dijit/form/TimeTextBox", "dojo/parser"
], function(lang, registry, ready) {
    ready(function() {
        var timeH = registry.byId("timeHours"),
            timeM = registry.byId("timeMins");
    });
});
```

Comment: In minutes field how can we show only 00 to 55 one time, currently with the code u mentioned 00 to 55 is displaying many times in minutes dropdown, please suggest. @Jase.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm working on Dojo and looking at lots of TimeTextBox questions on SO, I figured I can answer some of them.

Here's a JS Fiddle I made just for this question. I used increments of an hour and only display the hours, then I do the same for the minutes. If you want 5 minute intervals instead, change

```
pickerMax: 'T00:59:00',
clickableIncrement: 'T00:01:00',
visibleIncrement: 'T00:01:00'
```

to

```
pickerMax: 'T00:55:00',
clickableIncrement: 'T00:05:00',
visibleIncrement: 'T00:05:00'
```

NOTE: `pickerMin` and `pickerMax` require Dojo 1.10.4.

```
h = new dijit.form.TimeTextBox({
    constraints: {
        timePattern: 'HH',
        pickerMin: 'T00:00:00',
        pickerMax: 'T23:00:00',
        clickableIncrement: 'T01:00:00',
        visibleIncrement: 'T01:00:00'
    }
});
m = new dijit.form.TimeTextBox({
    constraints: {
        timePattern: 'mm',
        pickerMin: 'T00:00:00',
        pickerMax: 'T00:59:00',
        clickableIncrement: 'T00:01:00',
        visibleIncrement: 'T00:01:00'
    }
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/tfpjmbs2/1/