# dropdown list to show time

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

How can i show minutes in minutes textbox created using dojo.Please find the working sample http://jsfiddle.net/7de4onun/10/ .
**I want to show only 00 to 55 one time in minutes dropdown list**, could not able to get how to implement/show only minutes in minutes dropdown list.
Below is the code:

```
<input id="timeHours" width="2px" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox" required="true" data-dojo-props="constraints: { timePattern: 'HH', clickableIncrement: 'T01:05:00', visibleIncrement: 'T01:00:00', visibleRange: 'T24:00:00' }" />
:
<input id="timeMins" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox" required="true" data-dojo-props="constraints: { timePattern: 'mm', clickableIncrement: 'T00:05:00', visibleIncrement: 'T00:05:00', visibleRange: 'T00:60:00' }" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [time to display in dropdown lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167944/time-to-display-in-dropdown-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the hack :)

```
<input id="timeMins" 
   data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TimeTextBox" 
   required="true" 
   data-dojo-props="constraints: { 
       timePattern: 'mm', 
       clickableIncrement: 'T02:05:00', 
       visibleIncrement: 'T02:05:00', 
       visibleRange: 'T00:55:00' }" />
```

Seems like from `T00` to `T00` for dojo, is same as from `T00` to `T24`

Comment: Its still repeating twice in minutes dropdown list and +1 for effort. @jevgenig

Comment: Correct, sorry, let me fix it

Comment: There seem to be some bug or something. Check updated version. I've hacked it, and I believe it just increments 00 - 24, using 2:05 as increment, but the output is what you want :)

Comment: Thanks :) it worked.One more bug i noticed just now, please see http://jsfiddle.net/7de4onun/14/ . In hours textbox 12 is missing, is that because of the code ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jevgenig/7de4onun/15/ just change clickableIncrement: 'T01:05:00' to clickableIncrement: 'T01:00:00'